# Flex datagrid wordwrap customization

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, wrapper

I would like to use the word wrapper for datagrid header, the problem is that it cuts the word to a new line, what i need is to add - sign after the word cutted...

what i mean is:

admins-
trator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'll have to extend the DataGridHeader class to do this manually, then assign it as the headerRenderer on all your DataGridColumns.

This isn't a trivial task. You'll need to use line metrics to establish the length of the string, split it up yourself and add the requisite "-".

Comment: ok.. thanks for the answer.. i thought its related to word wrapper property, and thought i need to override the default wrapper.. dont you think this is possible????

Comment: It's certainly possible, but the standard word wrap functionality is very dumb and it's a much bigger job than it should be to change.